# Point two different domains to one ip address in route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, a-records

We have two DNS hosted zones in AWS Route53 i.e.,

1. dev-website.com
2. prod-website.com

We have a wordpress website sitting in EC2 instance.

I have created A record of dev-website.com to IP address, 243.234.212.12 , of EC2 instance . It's working fine.

Today we are deploying our services in prod & our prod wordpress is not ready yet. Meanwhile we want to point prod-website.com to same IP address as dev wordpress's i.e., 243.234.212.12.

I have configured A record in prod same as dev as follows.

dev-website.com  >>    243.234.212.12

prod-website.com  >>    243.234.212.12

Now, the issue is when I enter the prod-website.com in browser, it is redirecting to dev-website.com

Will there be any other configuration required in this kind of scenario.
Can someone help me with this issue?

Note: The ip address is used not the real one.

Comment: I think DNS is doing it's job, it seems like Wordpress is configured to do a redirect to dev-website.com

Comment: [Redirecting to old domain after migration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187574/redirecting-to-old-domain-after-migration?newreg=0dc44d3360fd40a5acc3b4224fb719cb) seems like similar issue, some configuration is needed to solve the redirection

Comment: Thank you both of you.
I ressolved it